# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__main_doctor.email

Tags: python, django, django-models

i was trying to change `null = False` and `Unique = True` in EmailField and after it started giving me this error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__main_doctor.email` I have run the commands `makemigrations` and `migrate` but it still giving me this error. I tried undo these and then run commands but it still giving me error.

here is my models.py file

```
    from django.db import models
    from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
    import os 
    # Create your models here.
    import datetime
    def get_file_path(request, filename):
        filename_original = filename
        nowTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
        filename = "%s%s" % (nowTime, filename_original)
        return os.path.join('uploads/', filename)
    
    
    class Doctor(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=100)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        speciality =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
        doc_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path ,null = False, blank = False)
        kycdocument = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path, null = False, blank = False)
    
    
    class Department(models.Model):
        dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        dept_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
        dept_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

here is forms.py file

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Doctor,Department
    
    
    class Doctorslist(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Doctor
            fields = ('name','phone_number','email', 'city', 'speciality', 'doc_image', 'kycdocument')
            # widgets = {
            #     'name':  forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            #     'email':  forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            #     'city':  forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            #     'speciality': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            # }   
    
    
    class Departmentform(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Department
            fields = ('dept_name','dept_Email','dept_password')
            widgets = {'dept_password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

This is Error

```
(env) C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\hospitalmanagement>python manage.py migrate        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, main, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying main.0008_auto_20211014_0005...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__main_doctor.email

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 138, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 571, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 360, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 283, in _remake_table
    self.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s" % (
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\DjangoPracticeProjects\blog_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__main_doctor.email
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question?

Comment: Added you check it now

Comment: what is the previous version of the `email` field? did you add the unique constraint later?

Comment: Yes, I added it later

Comment: you have duplicated emails in your column, check them and delete duplicated, then run python manage.py migrate again

Comment: if you have duplicated data in your column, django can't deduplicate them, you have to handle that

Answer (score 2):

It is because, in your old data of the DB, you have duplicated emails. you can remove all old data or find duplicated data and changing them.